# IIS Laravel upload file to AWS S3 Multipart return 500.0 error

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, iis

I can't figure it out what's going on with this. The requirement is to upload large files up to 25GB to storage on AWS S3. We have a laravel app running with no problems for a couple of years. So, I just add a controller to do the job with the `MultipartUploader` tool from AWS...

- Files up to 64mb are uploading with no problem
- Files larger than that, return a 500 0 error, and I find nothing on the log.

I've change the `upload_max_filesize` & `post_max_size` to 4G.

Here's the code...

```
    $s3Client = new S3Client([
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
        'version' => 'latest',
        'credentials' => $credentials
    ]);
    $source = fopen( $file['fileName']->getRealPath() , 'r');

    $storageClass = 'STANDARD_IA';
    $chunkSize = 100 * 1024 * 1024; // 100MB
    if(!isset($results['backup']['uploadId'])) {
        $response = $s3Client->createMultipartUpload([
            'Bucket' => $bucket,
            'Key' => $path,
            'StorageClass' => $storageClass,
            'Tagging' => '',
            'ServerSideEncryption' => 'AES256',
            'ContentType' => $file['fileName']->getMimeType(),
        ]);
        $results['backup']['uploadId'] = $response['UploadId'];
        $results['backup']['partNumber'] = 1;
    }
    //Reading parts already uploaded
    for($i = 1; $i < $results['backup']['partNumber']; $i++) {
        set_time_limit(0);
        if(!feof($source)) fread($source, $chunkSize); 
    }
     // Uploading next parts
    while(!feof($source)) {
        do {
            try {
                set_time_limit(0);
                $uploadSuccess = $s3Client->uploadPart([
                    'Bucket' => $bucket,
                    'Key' => $path,
                    'UploadId' => $results['backup']['uploadId'],
                    'PartNumber' => $results['backup']['partNumber'],
                    'Body' => fread($source, $chunkSize),
                ]);
                $results['uploadFile ' . $key] = ['status' => 'success', 'result' => $fileName ];
            } catch (MultipartUploadException $e) {
                rewind($source);
                $uploader = new MultipartUploader($s3Client, $source, [
                    'state' => $e->getState(),
                ]);
                $results['uploadFile ' . $key] = ['status' => 'error', 'result' => $e->getMessage() . "\n" ];
            }
        } while (!isset($uploadSuccess));

        $results['backup']['parts'][] = [
            'PartNumber' => $results['backup']['partNumber'],
            'ETag' => $uploadSuccess['ETag'],
        ];
        $results['backup']['partNumber']++;
            
    }
    fclose($source);

    $uploadSuccess = $s3Client->completeMultipartUpload([
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key' => $path,
        'UploadId' => $results['backup']['uploadId'],
        'MultipartUpload' => [
            'Parts' => $results['backup']['parts'],
        ],
    ]);
    unset($results['backup']);
    return $results;
```

Comment: you find nothing in what log? there is more than one place errors could be logged

Comment: nothing on the laravel.log - on the iis log I can find the sc-status sc-substatus and details, but its not helpfull

Comment: 500.0 sounds like something coming from IIS so maybe check if you need to increase the request size limits on IIS as well

Comment: yes, I did that as well

Answer (score 0):

You can set Maximum allowed content length in Request Filtering rules.
[image]
[image]

The default maximum upload is 30mb, you can change it as needed.

Comment: Yes, I did that... 500 error could be an app error. But it work until 64mb. So, it isn’t an app error. I think answer will be, to find a more explicit log. But I don’t know where or how. I just use the iis log and the laravel log.

Comment: You can enable fail request tracing to check what the problem is.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis